# SQL value does not populate ASP DropDownList control

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list control. 'Inputs' is the DB. Table is 'ApplicationName', and it has a random value assigned to it.

For some reason, when I click the Test Submit button, nothing is appearing in the control (DropDownList1).

```
protected void TestSubmit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize the database connector.
    SqlConnection connectSQL = new SqlConnection();

    // Send the connection string.
    connectSQL.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = localhost\SQLEXPRESS;" + 
        "Initial Catalog = Inputs; Integrated Security = SSPI";

    try
    {
        // Setup our command.
        SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Inputs", connectSQL);

        // Write the stored value in the text boxes.
        connectSQL.Open();

        SqlDataReader theReader;

        theReader = theCommand.ExecuteReader();
        theReader.Read();

        DropDownList1.Items.Add(theReader["ApplicationName"].ToString());

        theReader.Close();
        connectSQL.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        MessageBox("Oopsie: " + ee);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using a [SqlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz12d98w%28VS.80%29.aspx)? It'll be far less code for you to maintain and defend against defects for.

```
     <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1"
          runat="server"
          DataTextField="ApplicationName" 
          DataValueField="ApplicationName"
          DataSourceID="AppDataSource">
      </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:SqlDataSource
          id="AppDataSource"
          runat="server"
          DataSourceMode="DataReader"
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
          SelectCommand="SELECT ApplicationName FROM Inputs">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What if I have one row but multiple columns and each column will populate the dropdownlist? My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310610/how-to-split-sql-query-result-to-populate-a-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do a while(reader.read())

Then populate something like a dataset or a List, and then set the drop down lists data source to the dataset or list.

Answer (score 0):

If your table name is "ApplicationName"... shouldn't your SQL statement be `SELECT * FROM ApplicationName`?  Did you try looking to see if your reader had any results?

Answer (score 0):

If you match the columns selected in your database query with the DataTextField and DataValueField in the definition for your DropDownList, you should just need to do:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = theReader;  
DropDownList1.DataBind()
```

or even

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = theCommand.ExecuteReader();
```