# How to split sql query result to populate a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

The DataSet looks like this:

```
Spec1                                           Spec2                                           Spec3   Spec4   Spec5   Spec6   Spec7   Spec8   Spec9   Spec10
<a href="/spe.aspx?id=10" title="AI">AI</a>     <a href="/spe.aspx?id=40" title="BA">BA</a>
```

I would like to populate a dropdownlist:

```
<asp:dropdownlist ID="ddl1" runat="server"></asp:dropdownlist>
```

so the HTML output is this (an entry for each column instead of each row):

```
<select>
    <option value="/spe.aspx?id=10">AI</option>
    <option value="/spe.aspx?id=40">BA</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/804660/How-to-Parse-HTML-using-Csharp) to parse it out. And you'll need to (probably) use a `foreach` loop and a second `DataSet` (or a `Dictionary<string, string>`) object which you can put the values into and then use to data bind your DropDownList.

EDIT: Without the HTML Agility Pack:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (DataRow r in my.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in my.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        if (r[c] == DBNull.Value || r[c].ToString().Trim() == "")
           continue;
        string spec = r[c].ToString();
        string href = spec.Substring(spec.IndexOf("href=");
        href = href.Trim("\"").Substring(0, spec.IndexOf("\""));
        ....
        dict1.Add(href, val);
    }
}
ddl1.DataSource = dict1;
ddl1.DataBind();
```

You might be able to get an easier solution using the library but I'm not sure how well it handles a lack of a document and only having a single element. But that should demonstrate fairly well.

Comment: Thank you. Some code to start with would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Added some additional starting code. Hope it helps! I haven't tested it but it should give you a rough idea.

Comment: Great. That is a start. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing, how to check to see if the column is empty or null before doing the operation?

Comment: Thank you. You helped me start and I finished it. +1 and accepted.